# Consumer product equivalent to a power strip with a 5A circuit breaker?

Tags: electrical

I want to leave a portable induction burner on overnight, simmering soup stock at a very low power. Looking online, I've been somewhat alarmed by people's reports of electrical faults causing such induction burners to switch themselves to high power use---a fire hazard, since nobody is monitoring.

**I was wondering if there exists an off the shelf product roughly equivalent to a power strip with a built-in re-settable 5A (or 1A? not sure yet) circuit breaker.** The plan would be to always use the induction burner with the breaker when leaving it unattended. I know I could make this myself, but I really don't want to unless I can find some kind of incredibly convenient project box that has most of the work already done for me.

(Apologies if this belongs on a different stack exchange. I narrowed it down to diy and electrical engineering, and the whole point is that I don't want to do any engineering.)

Comment: I'm pretty good at geolocating askers, it's kinda my hat.  What I know from this is you're not in the UK.  For whatever reason, UK appliances all have fuses in the appliance plug. It would be trivial for a Briton to change a 10A cooker fuse for a 2A.

Comment: @Harper That's a cool idea, and I didn't know that about UK appliances. However, my UK counterpart wouldn't be able to use the induction burner at full power if he wanted to! From google and the (lack of) answers here, it seems like there really isn't something like an off the shelf current-limited power strip. I guess there just aren't enough uses for something like that.

Comment: @Harper Actually, now that I thought more about what you said, there's a good chance I can find a power strip that has a fuse inside of it (even if not advertised as such), and just replace that.

Answer (score 1):

#### Circuit protection is for FAULTS, not Regular Usage

If an induction burner is **designed** for long-term usage then extra circuit protection should not be necessary. If it is NOT designed for long-term usage then extra circuit protection is not enough. For example, leaving anything cooking for a long time has the possibility of all the liquid boiling out, which can result in problems (e.g., fires) that have nothing to do with wiring faults.

#### Get a Slow Cooker

A [Crockpot or Slow Cooker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow_cooker) is **designed** to be used for a long period of time - 12 to 24 hours. It typically includes a base with a covered heating element and a pot that sits on top and is specifically designed to match the base so that there are no exposed heating elements. In addition, the pot itself is often (though not in all brands/types) a ceramic pot that retains heat well and typically has a close fitting lid to help keep steam/liquids inside (though not super-tight like a pressure cooker).

Comment: [While rare, crockpots can catch fire too.](https://www.cookinglight.com/news/crock-pot-fire-this-is-us)

Comment: @Tyson True. I have seen burnt crockpots too. But starting with a device designed to be on for a long time for "overnight, simmering soup stock at a very low power" is better than starting with a device designed for shorter-term use.

Comment: @manassehkatz Thanks, I agree that the crockpot is the safest choice. But It's not versatile enough for me, and takes up too much space. I'm not worried about all the liquid boiling out, since the heat will be very low. Are there other potential problems that you know about?

Comment: @Alex Not specifically. I do realize a crockpot is not as versatile - it is great at slow speed, moderate at medium speed but utterly useless at doing anything fast. There are smaller crockpots available too. But in the end, yes that would mean 2 devices - crockpot for slow, induction for fast.